# Trying to output UTF-8 Text, and it doesn't work

Tags: java, utf-8

I have this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Decoder {
    public static void Decode() throws IOException{
        String input = "";
        input = readFile("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Pictures\\Binary.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      input = input.replace(" ","");
      System.out.println(input);
      String output = "";
      Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Pictures\\Binary2.txt")), "UTF8"));
      for(int i = 0; i <= input.length() - 8; i+=8)
      {
          int k = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+8), 2);
          out.append((char)k);
      }   
      out.close();
      System.out.println("Your File has been saved at C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Pictures\\Binary.txt");
    }
    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
              throws IOException 
            {
              byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
              return new String(encoded, encoding);
            }
}
```

and basically what I'm doing is converting a text file containing binary that can be decoded into text. It decodes successfully, but when outputting the file containing the output, all UTF-8 Characters are replaced with '?'. Why is this happening?

EDIT:
Example Input:

```
00111111 01010000 01001110 01000111 00001101 00001010 00011010 00001010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101 01001001 01001000 01000100 01010010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00001000 00000110 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111 00010101 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 01110011 01010010 01000111 01000010 00000000 00111111 00111111 00011100 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 01100111 01000001 01001101 01000001 00000000 00000000 00111111 00111111 00001011 00111111 01100001 00000101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001 01110000 01001000 01011001 01110011 00000000 00000000 00001110 00111111 00000000 00000000 00001110 00111111 00000001 00111111 01101111 00111111 01100100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011000 01110100 01000101 01011000 01110100 01010011 01101111 01100110 01110100 01110111 01100001 01110010 01100101 00000000 01110000 01100001 01101001 01101110 01110100 00101110 01101110 01100101 01110100 00100000 00110100 00101110 00110000 00101110 00110011 00111111 00111111 01010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101 01001001 01000100 01000001 01010100 00011000 01010111 01100011 00101000 00001000 01110011 01011011 00001011 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000001 00111111 00011110 01110011 00111111 00111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01001001 01000101 01001110 01000100 00111111 01000010 01100000 00111111
```

Expected output:

```
‰PNG


IHDR         Ä‰   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa      pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d   tEXtSoftware paint.net 4.0.3Œæ—P   
IDATWc(s[  ºs¾²    IEND®B`‚
```

Output gotten:

```
?PNG


IHDR         ?   sRGB ???   gAMA  ???a      pHYs  ?  ??o?d   tEXtSoftware paint.net 4.0.3??P   
IDATWc(s[  ?s??    IEND?B`?
```

Comment: Try to change UTF8 to UTF-8

Comment: @Pphoenix Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: @Pphoenix I think the problem isn't the file writer, it's the conversion losing the UTF-8 Formatting I think.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input to make it easier to test?

Comment: My other guess would be that `k` in `int k = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+8), 2);` produces a character that is outside of the character range, thus java does not know how to interpret the character and puts a `?` instead.

Comment: @Pphoenix The example input was too long for a comment so you can find it in the main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59918/discussion-between-user3042719-and-pphoenix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is binary data, you should write it to a binary file not a text file. Create your output simply like this:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.png");
```

I named your output with extension `.png` because your expected output looks like a PNG image.

And write bytes to your output like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= input.length() - 8; i += 8) {
    int k = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+8), 2);
    out.write(k);
}
```

**Improvements:**

You don't have to remove spaces from your input string as you can just skip them when iterating over the `String`:

```
// If spaces are not removed:
for(int i = 0; i <= input.length() - 9; i += 9) {              // NOTE THE  +9
    int k = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i+8), 2); // AND STILL +8 HERE
    out.write(k);
}
```

Also further, you don't even need to read the whole input file into memory as you can just read it by 8 or 9 byte chunks, as those provide a valid byte for the output file.

Comment: Thanks! I have one problem though... I changed it to what you said I should, but now it is giving me java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1240 (With the non-improved version)

Comment: Please note that I changed the condition in the `for`, I removed the `=` sign! **`i < input.length()`**

Comment: I did remove the = sign, and to make sure I copied and pasted what you put there and I still have the same error.

Comment: Then maybe your input contains a newline character at the end? I changed the condition back.

Comment: I guess it does because that works, but I'm still getting ? instead of UTF-8 Characters

Comment: You can't view your binary output in a text viewer. If it is a png file, open it with an image viewer. If the file is corrupt, then your input text might not be a valid binary encoding of the original file's content.

Comment: okay, Thanks. Maybe my encoder needs to be tweaked a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem with your input.
You expect your output to have the charcter `¾`in it. Looking at the input for that character I found:

The integer value for `¾` is decimal 190 (hex BE), which is `10111110` in binary.
The value in your input that corresponds to that place is equal to 63 (00111111), which is 3F in hex. U+003F    corresponds to `?   3f  QUESTION MARK` so your problem lies within your input.